# Incompatible Generic Types: Cannot specify sub-type when using .class with generic type

Tags: java, generics, types

There are many threads relating to Java Generics, and I'm having trouble sorting out why exactly Java doesn't support this (or alternatively, what I need to do to make it work).

```
public interface Thinger<T> {

    Class<? extends Thinger<T>> getThingers();
}

public class Thingy<Qwerty> implements Thinger<String> {

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Thinger<String>> getThingers() {
        return Thingx.class;
    }
}

public class Thingx implements Thinger<String> {

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Thinger<String>> getThingers() {
        return Thingy.class;    // Incompatible types error
    }
}
```

I can fix the compile error two ways, but both of them end up dropping some kind of typing information that I want to keep!

#### Option 1

Drop the generic `Qwerty` in `Thingy<Qwerty>`.

```
public class Thingy implements Thinger<String> {
    ..
// Ends up fixing the compile error in Thingx
```

#### Option 2

Drop the generic `String` in `Class<? extends Thinger<String>>`

```
public class Thingx implements Thinger<String> {

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Thinger> getThingers() {
        return Thingy.class;    // Fixed!
```

Comment: Whats the `<Qwerty>` supposed to do?

Comment: @tkausl `<Qwerty>` is a generic type. It could have been `<E>` or `<T>` or anything that doesn't exist.

Comment: @4castle Yea, sure, but he never uses it in the class and it's not a single letter but a weird name therefore I concluded he's trying to put a class-name there.

Comment: Option 2 doesn't quite work. It just creates a new error that you didn't properly implement the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thingy.class` returns a `Class<Thingy>` where `Thingy` is a raw type since it doesn't specify a value for `Qwerty`. Since, it's a raw type, the compiler is only aware of `Thingy` implementing `Thinger`, instead of `Thinger<String>`, since that information is lost due to type erasure.

To fix it, you can convert the `Class<Thingy>` to a `Class<? extends Thinger>` using [`Class#asSubclass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass-java.lang.Class-), and then the compiler allows the implicit cast to `Thinger<String>`.

```
return Thingy.class.asSubclass(Thinger.class);
```

This produces no compiler or runtime errors when tested:

```
Class<? extends Thinger<String>> c = new Thingx().getThingers();
System.out.println(c.getGenericInterfaces()[0]);
```

Output is:

```
Thinger<java.lang.String>
```

Comment: It's not a bug. This is the intended behavior.

Comment: @newacct Please show your sources. In my research `.class` returns a non-generic type, and not a raw type, meaning all genetic data is still in tact for the implemented interfaces.

Comment: I never said that `.class` has a raw type. `Thingy.class` has type `Class<Thingy>`. That is very clear from the specs. `Thingy` is a raw type.

Comment: @newacct Please actually cite the specs. Also, raw types can still have concrete generic super types.

Comment: Again, cite the specs about what? You keep saying "cite the specs" but it's never clear which part exactly you are not sure about. That `Thingy.class` has type `Class<Thingy>`? Or that the type `Thingy` is a raw type? All of those things are very easy to find in the specs. And no, raw types cannot be a subtype of its generic superclass. It's not possible to cite the non-existence of something (the absence of a rule allowing it to be a subtype means it is not a subtype) -- the burden of proof is on the person claiming it could be a subtype to show a rule that allows it to be a subtype.

Comment: @newacct I've cited the spec that says `Thingy` is not a raw type, since it in a non-generic context. You have not cited a spec that says `Thingy.class` returns a `Class<Thingy>` where `Thingy` is a raw type, because it isn't a raw type.

Comment: @newacct Notice that in the description of a class literal [at  §15.8.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2), it states that "*The type of `C.class`, where `C` is the name of a class, interface, or array type (§4.3), is `Class<C>`.*" Notice that it didn't say `Class<|C|>`

Comment: Umm... that perfectly agrees with everything I said. `Class<C>` where `C` is the name of the class `Thingy` *is* `Class<Thingy>`, which is exactly what I said. Because `C` is a name, it is always unparameterized. I don't know what you're trying to say.

Comment: @newacct No it doesn't. You keep claiming that `Thingy` is a raw type in `Class<Thingy>`. The spec does not indicate that it creates a raw type, unless you have some spec to share which contradicts the spec I cited.

Comment: Umm... you are contradicting the plain definition of raw type. A type either is a raw type or it is not based on the definition of raw type. There is no such thing as `Thingy` here being raw type and `Thingy` there not being raw type. That doesn't make sense. There is only one type written as `Thingy` and it satisfies the definition of a raw type.

Comment: @newacct The plain definition says "*The reference type that is formed by taking the name of a generic type declaration without an accompanying type argument list.*" That definition does not apply because `Thingy` is being used in a non-generic context. Therefore `Thingy` is not a generic type here. The JLS states that `Thingy` is defined as a generic type depending on the context. In the context of `.class`, it's a non-generic type.

Comment: @newacct There is such thing as `Thingy` being a raw type here, and not somewhere else. Please read the spec I cited again. A non-generic type is not a raw type because it isn't a generic type. The definition of a raw type only applies to generic types.

Comment: Yes, a non-generic type is not a raw type. `Thingy` is a generic class. The type `Thingy` is a raw type. The thing on the left side of `.class` is a `TypeName`, a "name", which has no concept of raw or not. The *name* (not a type) `C` is then used as a type in `Class<C>`, and here as a type it will be a raw type if it is the name of a generic class or interface.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122061/discussion-between-4castle-and-newacct).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having trouble sorting out why exactly Java doesn't support this

`Thingy.class` has type `Class<Thingy>`, which is not a subtype of `Class<? extends Thinger<String>>`, because `Thingy` is not a subtype of `Thinger<String>`.

Note that since `Thingy` is a generic class (it is declared with a type parameter), using `Thingy` by itself without a type argument is a *raw type*. When you use a raw type, you disable all generics, so the supertype of `Thingy` (the raw type) is `Thinger` (the raw type), not `Thinger<String>` (even though `Qwerty` is not involved in the relationship). This is similar to how if you call a method on a raw type like `Thingy`, all generics are turned off in the parameter and return types of the method, even if they have nothing to do with `Qwerty`. This is just one of the reasons to avoid raw types.

It works for `Thingx.class` because `Thingx` *is* a subtype of `Thinger<String>`, as `Thingx` is not a raw type because the class `Thingx` is not generic.

As others have noted, there doesn't seem to be any reason why `Thingy` is generic, as the type parameter `Qwerty` is never used inside `Thingy`. So the best choice would be to remove it.

Comment: I don't exactly understand.  Thingy *is a* subtype of Thinger<String>.  Also, `Qwerty` is used elsewhere.  The example doesn't use it for simplicity.

Comment: No, if you look at the [Java Specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.1), you will find `.class` listed as one of the "13 non-generic contexts". A non-generic type is explicitly defined as **not** a raw type. In other words, the type of `Thingx.class` and `Thingy.class` are identical.

Comment: @4castle: I am not sure what you've been reading but you are responding to words I did not write. I never said `.class` is a raw type. `Thingy.class` has type `Class<Thingy>` and `Thingx.class` has type `Class<Thingx>`. Where did I say those are raw types? `Class<something>` is obviously not a raw type as it is parameterized. I said `Thingy` is a raw type, which it is, by definition of raw type.

Comment: @lindseysawatzky: "Thingy is a subtype of Thinger<String>" No, it isn't. A raw type is not a subtype of a parameterized superclass. Look at the Java subtyping rules in the JLS. Nowhere does it say such a subtyping relationship is possible. In the section on raw types, you will see that the superclass of a raw type is the erasure of the superclass. `Thingy` is only a subtype of `Thinger` (the raw type), not `Thinger<anything>`.

Comment: @newacct Please provide more evidence. Even raw types can have parameterized super types when they are declared with a concrete type. [Observe this has no errors.](https://ideone.com/XsGVYC).

Comment: @newacct In my first comment, I meant to say the the context to the left of `.class` is a non-generic context.

Comment: @4castle: No, they can't. Just because you can assign one to the other does not mean one is a subtype of the other. You can implicitly convert between raw types and parameterized types (e.g. between `List` and `List<String>`) in both directions as a backward compatibility feature but that does not mean that they are both subtypes of each other. Read the Java subtyping rules in the JLS and you will see that there is no way a raw type can be a subtype of its parameterized superclass; it can only be a subtype of the erasure.

Comment: @4castle: I am not even sure what you mean by "context to the left of `.class`" since what goes before `.class` is not an expression by itself. Also, I don't understand what this has anything to do with this question or my answer.

Comment: @newacct It has to do with the answer because it shows that `.class` doesn't execute a type erasure on the class.

Comment: @4castle: That wouldn't make sense. How can you "execute a type erasure" on a name? Are you disputing that `Thingy.class` has type `Class<Thingy>` and `Thingx.class` has type `Class<Thingx>`?

Comment: I'm disputing that `Thingy.class` is not compatible with `Class<? extends Thinger<String>>`, because it is compatible according to the JLS, since `Thingy` refers to a non-generic (not raw) type that implements `Thinger<String>`.

Comment: @4castle: No, you are wrong. There is only one type `Thingy` and it is a raw type. Whether something is a raw type or not is decided solely by the definition of raw type.

Comment: @4castle: According to your logic, you can then take your `Class<Thingy>` and then use `.newInstance()` on it to get a `Thingy` back, and now this thing is not of a raw type?! That is absurd.

Comment: @newacct It's impossible to have a parameterized type at runtime. Generics are purely a compile-time construct. `.newInstance()` cannot create a parameterized instance, because generics don't exist at runtime. My logic is purely dealing with what should be legal at compile-time according to generics.

Comment: @4castle: I am talking about compile-time. The compile-time type of the expression.